# No /dev/hidraw device when I plug in a Yubikey

Tags: debian, usb, udev

I have a Yubikey NEO, and I'm trying to get it to work on Debian.

When I plug it in, I get udev events, but no /dev/hidraw? device.

Here's what I know so far:

`cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_HIDRAW)` gives:

```
CONFIG_HIDRAW=y
```

`lsusb -v -d 1050:0211` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 1050:0211 Yubico.com 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1050 Yubico.com
  idProduct          0x0211 
  bcdDevice            0.20
  iManufacturer           1 Yubico
  iProduct                2 Yubico WinUSB Gnubby (gnubby1)
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               30mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

If I run `udevadm monitor` as I plug and then unplug the Yubikey, I get:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[7941.975349] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[7941.975583] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [7941.985350] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [7942.998352] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[7945.487692] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[7945.487791] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [7945.488139] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [7945.488620] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
```

I have added udev rules, as recommended [here](https://www.yubico.com/faq/enable-u2f-linux/) and `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-u2f.rules` gives:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="u2f_end"

#KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", TAG+="uaccess"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0660"


LABEL="u2f_end"
```

(This didn't work when the commented line was uncommented either.)

I've tried installing `libhidapi-hidraw0`, but that hasn't seemed to work either.

I've also tried installing and running the Yubikey NEO manager, but both it and the yubikey personalization tool don't think any Yubikey device is plugged in, which why I think the blocker is the lack of a /dev/hidraw0 device (or something at a similar level).

I've reached the limits of both my knowledge of Linux and my ability to Google for solutions, so both further debugging suggestions and (if you know it) solutions would be helpful.

Comment: `lsusb` doesn't show any HID interface. And the product id doesn't correspond to any of [those I could find for Yubico keys](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-personalization/blob/master/ykcore/ykdef.h), which would explain the software doesn't find it.

Comment: Good catch!  I got this through work, so it may be development hardware or something?  I'll have to check with our IT department.

Comment: Possible. This is a random guess, but the key could be in a firmware installation/upgrade mode. I have a mouse that shows the same kind of interface when upgrading the firmware. From the docs on Yubico's website, the keys are configured with HID feature reports only, and the firmware isn't supposed to be modifiable.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem with a 0211 device I got from work.

Comment: I didn't, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful where you get your Yubikeys from, as some 2nd hand ones come from Google's test team. These will not work with the current version of NEO manager or the Personalization tool.

0x02xx devices are test devices.

If you kindly ask yubikey support for help, and give the device ID, and how you came to acquire said device (probably eBay) from personal experience they will be willing to RMA your device for free and send you a new one on their dime. Your results may vary.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It seem to me like the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-u2f.rules` is out of date, or at least gets overridden by a file in `/lib/udev/rules.d/`.  If you have installed the yubikey-personalization package, there should be a file `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-yubikey.rules`.  Open up the file, and add your test device ID (0x0210) to the list of known idVendors.  You should end up with something that looks like this.  This is from ubuntu wily werewolf, other OS versions may be slightly different, the key is to add 0211 to the list of product IDs:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="yubico_end"

# Udev rules for letting the console user access the Yubikey USB
# device node, needed for challenge/response to work correctly.

# Yubico Yubikey II
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1050", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0010|0110|0111|0114|0116|0211|0401|0403|0405|0407|0410", \
    ENV{ID_SECURITY_TOKEN}="1"

LABEL="yubico_end"
```

You then need to reload the udev rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`, then remove and reinsert your key.  This was enough to get it to work for me.